# Is it possible to access Cognito Forms from two accounts on the same WordPress site?

Tags: cognito-forms

My client has two Cognito accounts. Is it possible to access forms from both accounts on one WordPress site?

Answer (score 1):

I work for support for Cognito Forms.  For the WordPress plugin, only one account at a time is recognized.  However, Cognito Forms can be embedded into any web page, so you could support multiple forms that way.  If you have any problems with the embedding just contact customer support.